# Adding "%" after numbers in column that contains both text and numbers

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I've got a spreadsheet that contains text and numbers. My boss asked me to put a percentage sign after all of the numbers in a specific column. I know there's an easy way to do this but can't figure it out.

Example of text would be: 
Rated as a 70. Works great with team. 95 production and 98 accuracy. Needs confidence training.

Want it to read:
Rated as a 70%. Works great with team. 95% production and 98% accuracy. Needs confidence training. 
Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Can you use =concatenate(cellref, "%")

Comment: It added the % after the text not after the number

Comment: How about =cellref & "%"? This should convert every entry to text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using *VBA*.  Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Percentology()
    Dim r As Range, sin As String, sout As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, CH As String

    For Each r In Selection
        sin = r.Value
        sout = ""
        L = Len(sin)
        sout = Left(sin, 1)
        For i = 2 To L
            CH = Mid(sin, i, 1)
            If Not IsNumeric(CH) And IsNumeric(Right(sout, 1)) Then
                sout = sout & "%"
            End If
            sout = sout & CH
            If i = L And IsNumeric(CH) Then sout = sout & "%"
        Next i
        r.Value = sout
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

This uses a "crawler" technique rather than RegEx.

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: You are awesome and I appreciate your answer but I'm a complete newbie and don't know even where to put the macro.

Comment: @user7402286  then see my **EDIT#1**